Arbitrary Behavioral Voltage Source : Its not acting as it should be acting
I'm trying to make a circuit involving Arbitrary Behavioral Voltage Source, and the value of my BV is
V = V(vsin) > V(vtri) ? 12 : 0
This should make the output voltage only around 12V and 0V, but when I probe my simulation at the output, there are varying Voltages around 20~24. I don't understand why this is happening.

Have you tried if(,,) ? I don't recall ever trying it the way you wrote that. Not saying it doesn't work. It is just that the help file seems to suggest the if. Also, try specifying a very small step time. And also consider using .options plotwinsize=0, as well. Work on reducing this problem. Your .TRAN specifies 500 seconds! See if you can narrow this to a small time period and see if the same problem still occurs.

Have you the voltage B1 serial with the voltage Vsin?

So, I've tried both suggestions. I changed the code to V=IF(V(vsin) > V(vtri), 12, 0), and adjusted my simulation settings as .tran 0 0.1 0 1u. Also, I tried the .options plotwinsize=0. I didn't notice any difference and I tried make voltage B1 serial to Vsin, and it changed the output voltage of b1 as a more spikey form. but it still had the same problem outputting numbers like 20~24, instead of only 0 and 12V. I think it might be a problem with my wiring placement. Can someone specify more on how should I rearrange my circuits? Thanks in advance.

I think you should just wire to ground the left point of the behavioral source B1 (not wired to Vsin )... but I don't know LTSpice enough.

The voltage at node [B2] is higher than expected because source B1 is connected in series with source vsin1.  To fix this problem, simply:

Disconnect each source from all other sources.
Connect the negative pin of each source to GND.
Remove R2.


Thanks that helped the problem and the output voltages are showing as expected. I'm an amateur at circuit engineering so I would really appreciate it if you could specify further on why this solution solved the problem. Thanks for your help!

@성찬최 I think the confusion might be that you’re thinking the behavioral source has to be wired to the other two sources for the if() statement to work. This is not true. A behavioral source can be connected independently and the function(s) inside may reference any node voltage (or component current) anywhere on the schematic. In your case, it should have minus connected to ground and plus connected to a stub you can probe. I sounds to me like you added the resistor because you’d get an over-constrained matrix error when you shorted everything together.
